# Why my nginx always redirect me to an url domain when I enter http ip address

Tags: nginx, redirect, dns, ssl-certificate, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 server, with nginx and tomcat configured. Recently both my domain URL and my SSL certification expired. I purchased a new one. But before that, I rollback my nginx configuration to no-SSL version(HTTP) instead of HTTPS.
But the weird thing happen is that when I typed into my IP address, it doesn't work(it's expected to display my home page) but my IP address on the address bar is changed to my expired domain URL (of course it doesn't work at all). I don't have a cache on my browser, I tried it on new browser, new phone etc. got same result.

I checked everything I configured in my nginx, tomcat etc. nothing left relating to the URL domain. But still got that annoying redirecting...

Other than that, I can't access my tomcat neither via [ip:port] but can still call API on my tomcat application. So is it a DNS problem?

My nginx config are as below: (by the way, it used to work before I got https)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

in conf.d:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location ~ \.(jsp|jspx|do|action)?$
    {
        #=============tomcat.....============
        root /usr/local/tomcat/webapps;
        index index.jsp index.jspx index.do;
        #==========Nginx.....============
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #=== .....jsp .jspx .do .action ..........(tomcat)===
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: 1) Nginx is not redirecting the browser to a domain name URL. 2) Either the browser received a permanent redirect previously that it now remembers or 3) your web server application is redirecting. 4) Try from a different browser and possibly a different machine.

Comment: Thanks John. it fixed itself after a few days, i did nothing. Actually i ran a test then i reboot my sever, then put the ip to see if still redirect without nginx. it did. So i guessed it should be the dns but no idea how to fix it. yesterday i tried again, it worked..

Answer (score 0):

It fixed itself after a few days(About a week), while I did nothing.

Actually I ran a test that i reboot my sever, during reboot, I put the IP to see if still redirect without nginx. it did. So i guessed it should be the DNS but no idea how to fix it.

Yesterday I tried again, it worked. I guess it's because the DNS cache expired.